# Get Dictionary Keys From NumPy Array and Values From Increment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a large NumPy array (with 100,000,000 elements) that has unique and sorted values. The array may be generated with inefficiently with something like this (it will eat up your memory since the array is large but my array is derived efficiently from another source).

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.choice(9509413522, size=100_000_000, replace=False)  # this will take a ton of memory!
x = np.sort(x)
```

With this array, I want to create a Python dictionary where the keys are the unique array elements and the values are the corresponding array indices. Typically, I could do:

```
some_dict = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(x)}
```

But this takes too long for the large array (size 100,000,000 elements!) and I was hoping that there was a faster way to accomplish this.

Ultimately, I have some array `y` (with redundant elements) that I need to quickly convert to its corresponding value from `some_dict` by doing:

```
np.array([some_dict[k] for k in y])

# or, alternatively

np.vectorize(some_dict.get)(y)
```

Comment: Why does all of this need to be generated and held in memory in one go? I'm curious what you're trying to do

Comment: Making `x` a generator. Then only one element is stored in the memory and values are calculated on demand.

Comment: It's not pretty, but you could put that array into a pandas DataFrame and then do something like a pivot (or something of the sort) without reindexing. Then the new indexes should be the old values, and the old values the new indexes.